# How to run functions outside websocket loop in python (tornado)

Tags: python, websocket, tornado

I'm trying to set up a small example of a public Twitter stream over websockets.  This is my websocket.py, and it's working.

What I'm wondering is: how can I interact with the websocket from 'outside' the class WSHandler (ie. not only answer when receiving a message from websocket.js)?  Say I want to run some other function within this same script that would post "hello!" every five seconds and send that to the websocket (browser) without any interaction from client-side. How could I do that?

So it's kind of a fundamental beginner's question, I suppose, about how to deal with classes as those below. Any pointers in any direction would be greatly appreciated!

```
import os.path
import tornado.httpserver
import tornado.websocket
import tornado.ioloop
import tornado.web

# websocket
class FaviconHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        self.redirect('/static/favicon.ico')

class WebHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        self.render("websockets.html")

class WSHandler(tornado.websocket.WebSocketHandler):
    def open(self):
        print 'new connection'
        self.write_message("Hi, client: connection is made ...")

    def on_message(self, message):
        print 'message received: \"%s\"' % message
        self.write_message("Echo: \"" + message + "\"")
        if (message == "green"):
            self.write_message("green!")

    def on_close(self):
        print 'connection closed'



handlers = [
    (r"/favicon.ico", FaviconHandler),
    (r'/static/(.*)', tornado.web.StaticFileHandler, {'path': 'static'}),
    (r'/', WebHandler),
    (r'/ws', WSHandler),
]

settings = dict(
    template_path=os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), "static"),
)

application = tornado.web.Application(handlers, **settings)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    http_server = tornado.httpserver.HTTPServer(application)
    http_server.listen(8888)
    tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.instance().start()
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You could call a

```
IOLoop.add_timeout(deadline, callback)
```

that calls the callback at specified deadline timeout (one shot, but you can reschedule), or use the

`tornado.ioloop.PeriodicCallback` if you have a more periodic task.

See: http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/ioloop.html#tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.add_timeout

**Update: some example**

```
import datetime

def test():
    print "scheduled event fired"
...

if __name__ == "__main__":
    http_server = tornado.httpserver.HTTPServer(application)
    http_server.listen(8888)
    main_loop = tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.instance()
    # Schedule event (5 seconds from now)
    main_loop.add_timeout(datetime.timedelta(seconds=5), test)
    # Start main loop
    main_loop.start()
```

it calls `test()` after 5 seconds.

**Update 2:**

```
import os.path
import tornado.httpserver
import tornado.websocket
import tornado.ioloop
import tornado.web

# websocket
class FaviconHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        self.redirect('/static/favicon.ico')

class WebHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        self.render("websockets.html")

class WSHandler(tornado.websocket.WebSocketHandler):
    def open(self):
        print 'new connection'
        self.write_message("Hi, client: connection is made ...")
        tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.instance().add_timeout(datetime.timedelta(seconds=5), self.test)

    def on_message(self, message):
        print 'message received: \"%s\"' % message
        self.write_message("Echo: \"" + message + "\"")
        if (message == "green"):
            self.write_message("green!")

    def on_close(self):
        print 'connection closed'

    def test(self):
        self.write_message("scheduled!")

handlers = [
    (r"/favicon.ico", FaviconHandler),
    (r'/static/(.*)', tornado.web.StaticFileHandler, {'path': 'static'}),
    (r'/', WebHandler),
    (r'/ws', WSHandler),
]

settings = dict(
    template_path=os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), "static"),
)

application = tornado.web.Application(handlers, **settings)

import datetime

if __name__ == "__main__":
    http_server = tornado.httpserver.HTTPServer(application)
    http_server.listen(8888)
    tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.instance().start()
```

Comment: thanks. but where exactly? i've tried calling the WSHandler, but get "must be called with WSHandler instance..."

Comment: I added some example using add_timeout().

Comment: you wouldn't happen to know how to call the `WSHandler` from `test()`? So that I can call `self.write_message()` from there?

Comment: IOLoop.instance() is a singleton (in a typical use). You could call instance() many times and the same singleton will be returned.

Comment: See the second update. It send a scheduled message after 5 seconds on connect.

Comment: Awesome! Thanks so much for your stellar help!

Comment: I have a follow-up Q here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12481670/passing-data-between-classes-in-tornado-with-websocket

Answer (score 17):

I stumbled upon similar problem. Here is my solution. Hope this will be helpful to someone out there

```
wss = []
class wsHandler(tornado.websocket.WebSocketHandler):
    def open(self):
        print 'Online'
        if self not in wss:
            wss.append(self)

    def on_close(self):
        print 'Offline'
        if self in wss:
            wss.remove(self)

def wsSend(message):
    for ws in wss:
        ws.write_message(message)
```

To send message to your websockets simply use this:

```
wsSend(message)
```

**wsSend update**

I've been getting exceptions with wsSend once in a while. In order to fix it I've modified code a bit to following:

> ```
> def wsSend(message):
>     for ws in wss:
>         if not ws.ws_connection.stream.socket:
>             print "Web socket does not exist anymore!!!"
>             wss.remove(ws)
>         else:
>             ws.write_message(message)
> ```

Comment: Brand new to Tornado so..... would you mind adding the necessary boilerplate to this very promising answer, as I'd like to see how it would work with (if I understand correctly) more than one websocket handler. That is could you give an example of the if \_\_name\_\_ == "\_\_main\_\_" block that would initialize the IOLoop(s?) and the handler(s?). Seems very elegant at first glance.

Comment: Thomas, I would love to help you but its been quite a while also I am not an expert at Tornado either. But as far as I remember Tornado has excellent documentation and you can always browse source code. Good luck!

Answer (score 3):

One way to also do this is to use a **pub-sub** module.

Meaning you have your connections *subscribe* to it, and rather than setting timeouts for every single connection, you just set one timeout to *publish* after said period of time.

Probably one of the most implemented is **redis**. There are also some modules specifically for tornado: [toredis](https://github.com/mrjoes/toredis/blob/master/tests/test_handler.py) or [brükva](https://github.com/evilkost/brukva) for example.

Of course this might not be necessary for just a simple page, but scales really well and is also very nice to maintain/extend once you've set it up.