# Passing data between classes in Tweepy and Tornado WebSocket

Tags: python, websocket, tornado, tweepy

I have two main modules, Tornado WebSocket and Tweepy Streaming, and I'm trying to get them to talk to each other.

Under `on_status` in the `StdOutListener` Tweepy class below (marked with `<--`), I'd like to call the `WSHandler.on_message` Tornado class higher up, with data passed from `on_status`.

I'm not able to do so however, as I get error-messages related to undefined instances etc. with the code below. Any help greatly appreciated!

(Also, the only non-blocking way I've managed to run both modules at the same time is with threading, as the `IOLoop.add_callback` does not keep `StdOutListener` from blocking. I'd love to know why or if this implementation is recommended. Thanks!)

```
import os.path
import tornado.httpserver
import tornado.websocket
import tornado.ioloop
import tornado.web
import threading
import time
import datetime

# websocket
class FaviconHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        self.redirect('/static/favicon.ico')

class WebHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        self.render("websockets.html")

class WSHandler(tornado.websocket.WebSocketHandler):
    def open(self): 
        cb = tornado.ioloop.PeriodicCallback(self.spew, 1000, io_loop=main_loop)
        cb.start()
        print 'new connection'
        self.write_message("Hi, client: connection is made ...")

    def on_message(self, message):
        print 'message received: \"%s\"' % message
        self.write_message("Echo: \"" + message + "\"")
        if (message == "green"):
            self.write_message("green!")

    def on_close(self):
        print 'connection closed'

    def spew(self):
        msg = 'spew!'
        print(msg)
        self.on_message(msg)

handlers = [
    (r"/favicon.ico", FaviconHandler),
    (r'/static/(.*)', tornado.web.StaticFileHandler, {'path': 'static'}),
    (r'/', WebHandler),
    (r'/ws', WSHandler),
]

settings = dict(
    template_path=os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), "static"),
)

application = tornado.web.Application(handlers, **settings)


# tweepy
from tweepy.streaming import StreamListener
from tweepy import OAuthHandler
from tweepy import Stream
import simplejson as json


# new stream listener 
class StdOutListener(StreamListener, WSHandler):
    """ A listener handles tweets are the received from the stream. 
    This is a basic listener that just prints received tweets to stdout.

    """

    # tweet handling
    def on_status(self, status):
        print('@%s: %s' % (status.user.screen_name, status.text))
        WSHandler.on_message(status.text) # <--- THIS is where i want to send a msg to WSHandler.on_message

    # limit handling
    def on_limit(self, track):
        return

    # error handling
    def on_error(self, status):
        print status


def OpenStream():
    consumer_key="[redacted]"
    consumer_secret="[redacted]"
    access_token="[redacted]"
    access_token_secret="[redacted]"
    keyword = 'whatever'

    l = StdOutListener()
    auth = OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
    auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_token_secret)
    stream = Stream(auth, l, gzip=True) 
    stream.filter(track=[keyword])



if __name__ == "__main__":
    threading.Thread(target=OpenStream).start()
    http_server = tornado.httpserver.HTTPServer(application)
    http_server.listen(8888)
    main_loop = tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.instance()
#   main_loop.add_callback(OpenStream)
    main_loop.start()
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`on_message` is an instance method, not a class method. You need to call it on an instance, like this:

```
handler = WSHandler()
handler.on_message('hello world')
```

However, you can't just do that as instances need to be created by a browser connection in order to actually send and receive messages.

What you probably want is to keep a list of open connections ([the Tornado websocket demo is a good example of this](https://github.com/facebook/tornado/blob/master/demos/websocket/chatdemo.py)):

```
class WSHandler(tornado.websocket.WebSocketHandler):
    connections = []

    def open(self):
        self.connections.append(self)

    ....

    def on_close(self):
        self.connections.remove(self)
```

then, in `StdOutListener.on_status`, you can do something like:

```
for connection in WSHandler.connections:
    connection.write_message(status.text)
```