# python Tornado websockets how to send message every X seconds?

Tags: python, websocket, tornado

I am trying to cobble together a test which allows websockets clients to connect to a Tornado server and I want the Tornado server to send out a message to all clients every X seconds.

The reason I am doing this is because wbesockets connections are being silently dropped somewhere and I am wondering of periodic "pings" sent by the websockets server will maintain the connection.

I'm afraid it's a pretty noobish question and the code below is rather a mess. I just don't have my head wrapped around Tornado and scope enough to make it work.

```
import tornado.httpserver
import tornado.websocket
import tornado.ioloop
import tornado.web
import tornado.gen
import time
from tornado import gen

class WSHandler(tornado.websocket.WebSocketHandler):
    def open(self):
        print 'http://mailapp.crowdwave.com/girlthumb.jpg'
        self.write_message("http://www.example.com/girlthumb.jpg")

    def on_message(self, message):
        print 'Incoming message:', message
        self.write_message("http://www.example.com/girlthumb.jpg")


    def on_close(self):
        print 'Connection was closed...'

@gen.engine
def f():
    yield gen.Task(tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.instance().add_timeout, time.time() + 8)
    self.write_message("http://www.example.com/x.png")
    print 'x'

@gen.engine
def g():
     yield gen.Task(tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.instance().add_timeout, time.time() + 4)
     self.write_message("http://www.example.com/y.jpg")
     print 'y'

application = tornado.web.Application([
    (r'/ws', WSHandler),
    ])

if __name__ == "__main__":
    tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.instance().add_callback(f)
    tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.instance().add_callback(g)
    http_server = tornado.httpserver.HTTPServer(application)
    http_server.listen(8888)
    tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.instance().start()
```

Answer (score 9):

Why don't you try write a scheduler inside it? :)

```
def schedule_func():
    #DO SOMETHING#

#milliseconds
interval_ms = 15
main_loop = tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.instance()
sched = tornado.ioloop.PeriodicCallback(schedule_func,interval_ms, io_loop = main_loop)
#start your period timer
sched.start()
#start your loop
main_loop.start()
```

Answer (score 3):

Found that the accepted answer for this is almost exactly what I want:

[How to run functions outside websocket loop in python (tornado)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12479054/how-to-run-functions-outside-websocket-loop-in-python-tornado?rq=1)

With a slight modification, the accepted answer at the above link continually sends out ping messages.  Here is the mod:

Change:

```
def test(self):
    self.write_message("scheduled!")
```

to:

```
def test(self):
    self.write_message("scheduled!")
    tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.instance().add_timeout(datetime.timedelta(seconds=5), self.test)
```