# [Python][Tornado] Is it possible to have multi websocket with different port & message in one python program?

Tags: python, websocket, tornado

I am a newbie in Python. I am now having a project that using a raspberry pi to connect to local web, a web server & a mobile apps via websocket. Both of them are interactive. I can now communicate with each of them separately with 3 different program. But I face some problems when I want to integrate them into 1.

I read a number of post in here & find that all answers suggest to use a list to store each websocket and all of them sending the same message. Is it possible to send different message? Maybe something this

```
import tornado.ioloop
import tornado.web
import tornado.websocket

class WebSocketHandler_web(tornado.websocket.WebSocketHandler):
    def __init__(self, application, **kwargs):
        pass

    def open(self):
        # do something

    def on_message(self, msg):
        # do something

    def on_close(self):
        # do something

class WebSocketHandler_mobile(tornado.websocket.WebSocketHandler):
    def __init__(self, application, **kwargs):
        pass

    def open(self):
        # do something

    def on_message(self, msg):
        # do something

    def on_close(self):
        # do something

class WebSocketHandler_server(tornado.websocket.WebSocketHandler):
    def __init__(self, application, **kwargs):
        pass

    def open(self):
        # do something

    def on_message(self, msg):
        # do something

    def on_close(self):
        # do something

app_web    = tornado.web.Application([(r'/ws/', WebSocketHandler_web),])
app_mobile = tornado.web.Application([(r'/ws/', WebSocketHandler_mobile),])
app_server = tornado.web.Application([(r'/ws/', WebSocketHandler_server),])

def main_task():
    # do something
    if(mode == 1):
        webSocket_web.write_message("Mode 1")
    elif(mode == 2):
        webSocket_mobile.write_message("Mode 2")
    elif(mode == 3):
        webSocket_server.write_message("Mode 3")
    # do something

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app_web.listen(7777)
    app_mobile.listen(8888)
    app_server.listen(9999)
    webSocket_web    = WebSocketHandler_web(app_web)
    webSocket_mobile = WebSocketHandler_mobile(app_mobile)
    webSocket_server = WebSocketHandler_server(app_server)
    tornado.ioloop.PeriodicCallback(main_task,1000).start()
    tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.instance.start()
```

But seems that websocket.**init** needs a parameter request. What is that?

Comment: Seems that using a list is a must for sending message outside the WebSocketHandler Class
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12479054/how-to-run-functions-outside-websocket-loop-in-python-tornado

Answer (score 1):

*Is it possible to send different message* Just iterate over a list of stored websockets and send different message, simple as that.

*init needs a parameter request* Tornado on each incoming request creates an instance of a request handler, and request is passed to init to bind a handler to request. When you override an init method in your handler you should follow [parent's method interface](https://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/_modules/tornado/websocket.html#WebSocketHandler). Don't worry about value of request argument, tornado will pass it for you.